# PowerMockito mock abstract and non-public parent method that child class doesn't have

Tags: mocking, abstract-class, powermockito

Hi I have a code like this:
```

```
abstract class AbstractBaseClass {
  public String method() {
    return "AbstractBaseClass.method";
  }
}

public class ChildClass extends AbstractBaseClass {
  public String start() {
  }
}

@Test
public void test() {
  ChildClass child = mock(ChildClass.class);
  when(child.method()).thenReturn("my mock string");

  System.out.println(child.method()); // AbstractBaseClass.method
}
```

```
The code actually runs the parent class method instead of my mocked one. So how to mock a parent class considering it's abstract and non-public class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: Update to a newer version of Mockito. This works with mockito 2.7.22 and Java 1.8.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class Mockito {

    abstract class AbstractBaseClass {
        public String method() {
            return "AbstractBaseClass.method";
        }
    }

    public class ChildClass extends AbstractBaseClass {
        public String start() {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ChildClass child = mock(ChildClass.class);
        when(child.method()).thenReturn("my mock string");

        assertThat(child.method(), is("my mock string")); // AbstractBaseClass.method
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it mean that all versions above 2.7.22 of mockito and Java 1.8 has this functionality in place?

Comment: No, but I think so. Which versions of mockito and java are you using?

Comment: Java 1.8 and Mockito 2.6.4

Comment: I just tested with Mockit 2.6.4 and the Test above still passes. Have you tried the same with your configuration?

Comment: And how did you configure your dependencies? Do you use maven for this?

Comment: No, I use ANT. Then this is very strange.

Comment: Please provide us with your ant script.